# Ubuntu 22 LTS crashes repeatedly on 2023 Asus ROG Zephyrus G14

Tags: drivers, nvidia, asus, bios

I recently bought this laptop for work. I spend a lot of time coding and building the Android os. This workflow is a lot easier in Ubuntu, and I have successfully used Asus laptops in the past.

This laptop had a LOT of problems on bring up, all bar bluetooth were eventually fixed, I sorted out BT with a USB dongle. But as time has gone on the laptop has crashed more and more often. I've pasted the last number of lines from syslog into this post. Is there a BIOS setting I need to change, or some driver I need to update? I'm a bit terrified to touch the Nvidia drivers as they were the main source of crashes and bugs in the early days with this laptop :'( They seem stable now...?

```
Jan 29 09:42:41 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.013793] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.341325] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.341336] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.341339] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.341342] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.968446] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.968460] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.968464] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.968469] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.995691] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.995709] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.995714] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   66.995720] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:43 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   67.696827] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:43 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   67.696841] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:43 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   67.696844] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:43 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   67.696846] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 google-chrome.desktop[4623]: Opening in existing browser session.
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 geoclue[1660]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: geoclue.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.128790] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.128808] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.128813] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:44 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.128818] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.938330] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.938379] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.938388] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   69.938396] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:45 ZephyrusG14 chrome-pkooggnaalmfkidjmlhoelhdllpphaga-Default.desktop[4309]: INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Jan 29 09:42:48 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   72.861764] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:48 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   72.861777] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:48 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   72.861780] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:48 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   72.861782] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:49 ZephyrusG14 chrome-pkooggnaalmfkidjmlhoelhdllpphaga-Default.desktop[4309]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Jan 29 09:42:50 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   75.208770] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:50 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   75.208793] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:50 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   75.208800] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:50 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   75.208807] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:51 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jan 29 09:42:52 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   76.272697] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:52 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   76.272713] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:52 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   76.272716] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:52 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   76.272720] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:51 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   78.632163] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   78.632183] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   78.632188] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   78.632193] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2236]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Jan 29 09:42:54 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2236]: unable to update icon for livepatch
Jan 29 09:42:57 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   81.787308] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:42:57 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   81.787358] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:42:57 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   81.787363] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:42:57 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   81.787367] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.343387] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.343403] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.343407] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.343412] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.353600] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.353618] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.353623] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   85.353627] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   86.048931] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   86.048962] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   86.048969] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:43:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [   86.048975] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:43:20 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  104.731264] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:43:20 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  104.731285] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:43:20 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  104.731291] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:43:20 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  104.731299] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jan 29 09:43:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jan 29 09:43:29 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-report[1913]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 120s"
Jan 29 09:43:51 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jan 29 09:43:58 ZephyrusG14 NetworkManager[695]: <warn>  [1706550238.8479] device (wlp2s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
Jan 29 09:43:58 ZephyrusG14 NetworkManager[695]: <info>  [1706550238.8480] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 09:43:58 ZephyrusG14 NetworkManager[695]: <warn>  [1706550238.8486] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'EvergreenTerrace'
Jan 29 09:43:58 ZephyrusG14 NetworkManager[695]: <info>  [1706550238.8488] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 09:43:58 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jan 29 09:44:03 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  147.846812] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:03 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  147.846842] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:03 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  147.846849] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:03 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  147.846855] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:44:16 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  160.937504] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:16 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  160.937524] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:16 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  160.937529] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:16 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  160.937534] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:44:21 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  165.306261] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:21 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  165.306286] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:21 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  165.306292] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:21 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  165.306299] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:44:34 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  179.068123] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:34 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  179.068154] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:34 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  179.068160] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:34 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  179.068167] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:44:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  186.435817] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  186.435840] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  186.435845] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  186.435851] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:44:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  191.424649] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:44:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  191.424680] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:44:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  191.424686] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:44:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  191.424693] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:45:11 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  215.887839] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:45:11 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  215.887861] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:45:11 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  215.887868] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:45:11 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  215.887875] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:45:39 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-report[1913]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 240s"
Jan 29 09:46:39 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Jan 29 09:46:39 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:46:39 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Jan 29 09:46:40 ZephyrusG14 acvpnagent[775]: Function: GetSettings File: ../../vpn/Agent/ServicePluginMgr.cpp Line: 289 m_pIServicePlugin is NULL
Jan 29 09:46:40 ZephyrusG14 acvpnagent[775]: message repeated 4 times: [ Function: GetSettings File: ../../vpn/Agent/ServicePluginMgr.cpp Line: 289 m_pIServicePlugin is NULL]
Jan 29 09:46:48 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.102' (uid=1000 pid=5159 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Created slice Slice /app/org.gnome.Terminal.
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jan 29 09:46:49 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started VTE child process 5185 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5162.
Jan 29 09:47:04 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5572312b4320] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:04 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x557233461b10] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:04 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x557233465820] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:14 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[693]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.34' (uid=0 pid=718 comm="/usr/lib/snapd/snapd " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 09:47:14 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Jan 29 09:47:14 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jan 29 09:47:14 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Jan 29 09:47:21 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Consumed 1.257s CPU time.
Jan 29 09:47:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5572312b4320] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x557233461f00] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:23 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x557233465ba0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:47:25 ZephyrusG14 chrome-pkooggnaalmfkidjmlhoelhdllpphaga-Default.desktop[4309]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Jan 29 09:47:32 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jan 29 09:47:32 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.104' (uid=1000 pid=5300 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real --wait " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 09:47:32 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jan 29 09:47:33 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jan 29 09:47:33 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jan 29 09:47:33 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started VTE child process 5326 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5303.
Jan 29 09:47:40 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started snap.code.code-f4b56461-3c18-4716-b941-7ec336e26d37.scope.
Jan 29 09:47:41 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  365.406316] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:47:41 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  365.406335] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:47:41 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  365.406340] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:47:41 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  365.406345] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:47:44 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:48:04 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  388.308013] workqueue: pm_runtime_work hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
Jan 29 09:48:49 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: snap.code.code-f4b56461-3c18-4716-b941-7ec336e26d37.scope: Consumed 45.628s CPU time.
Jan 29 09:49:10 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  454.383636] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:49:10 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  454.383700] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:49:10 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  454.383709] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:49:10 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  454.383715] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:49:49 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-report[1913]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 480s"
Jan 29 09:49:58 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
Jan 29 09:49:58 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started VTE child process 5745 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 5303.
Jan 29 09:50:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  505.591451] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:50:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  505.591477] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:50:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  505.591484] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:50:01 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  505.591490] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:50:31 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  535.321894] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:50:31 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  535.321923] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:50:31 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  535.321927] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:50:31 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  535.321932] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:50:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  550.162259] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:50:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  550.162287] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:50:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  550.162293] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:50:45 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  550.162300] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.43' (uid=1000 pid=2236 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[1937]: [session uid=1000 pid=1937] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[693]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.190' (uid=1000 pid=5771 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 nautilus[5771]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5572312b4320] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x557233461330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:50:55 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x557233465120] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:50:56 ZephyrusG14 dbus-daemon[693]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 29 09:50:56 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 29 09:50:58 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowGroup>:0x5572312b4320] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:50:58 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x557233461330] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:50:58 ZephyrusG14 gnome-shell[2236]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x557233465120] is on because it needs an allocation.
Jan 29 09:51:10 ZephyrusG14 gvfsd[5809]: got no contact to IPC$
Jan 29 09:51:15 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  580.116067] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:51:15 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  580.116098] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:51:15 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  580.116105] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:51:15 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  580.116111] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:51:26 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:54:36 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  781.089706] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:54:36 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  781.089738] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:54:36 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  781.089744] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:54:36 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  781.089750] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:54:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  791.312946] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:54:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  791.312964] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:54:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  791.312969] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:54:47 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  791.312974] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:54:51 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  796.184820] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:54:51 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  796.184851] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:54:51 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  796.184856] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:54:51 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  796.184860] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:55:56 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  860.677358] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:55:56 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  860.677381] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:55:56 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  860.677386] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:55:56 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [  860.677391] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:56:40 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jan 29 09:56:40 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 29 09:56:40 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 29 09:57:59 ZephyrusG14 ubuntu-report[1913]: level=error msg="data were not delivered successfully to metrics server, retrying in 960s"
Jan 29 09:58:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1026.987008] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:58:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1026.987039] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:58:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1026.987045] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:58:42 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1026.987052] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
Jan 29 09:58:50 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Jan 29 09:58:50 ZephyrusG14 systemd[1901]: Started snap.code.code-c2e3890d-c749-4836-95b1-7db1462607a0.scope.
Jan 29 09:58:53 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1037.503008] pcieport 0000:00:02.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:04:00.0
Jan 29 09:58:53 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1037.503021] nvme 0000:04:00.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jan 29 09:58:53 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1037.503023] nvme 0000:04:00.0:   device [15b7:5017] error status/mask=00000001/0000e000
Jan 29 09:58:53 ZephyrusG14 kernel: [ 1037.503025] nvme 0000:04:00.0:    [ 0] RxErr                  (First)
```

Comment: "Corrected error received" means there is a hardware problem with your RAM and cables. The firmware is only notifying Ubuntu about these problems. There is nothing Ubuntu can do to fix this.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for that info, that's super helpful! Is there a way to tell from the log if this problem can be fixed with a RAM replacement? Upgrading the RAM on the Zephyrus isn't all that bad, so if it's possible and if it would fix the issue then I'm down to give it a try!

Comment: I don't know anything that would say for sure. But you "bought this laptop for work." Couldn't you try asking your coworkers or IT department whether you can borrow the RAM sticks in a spare laptop to test this, then return the sticks immediately and make your purchasing decision?

Comment: The company I work for is a bit weird, and my situation within the company is also weird... They don't technically support remote work for employees, but one of my requirements for accepting the job was being allowed to do my PhD, which required being able to work remotely... Long story short: I'm the only person in my team using a laptop for this job, everyone else is using a desktop, and I paid for this laptop personally so it's 100% my responsibility.

Comment: Another options, assuming the problem is localized, is to run memtest86 and disable the problematic memory regions. Yet, I'm still concerned that your nvme errors may lead to data loss. If you "recently bought this laptop," then I would return it because it is clearly defective

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the advice, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 and i have it since 2021, i have similar problems with my laptop when i install ubuntu or debian in dual boot along windows i have a lot of problems. the only way to seems to work is with a vm or docker and ubuntu or debian, also if you have windows you can try with the windows wsl, i know that this dont resolve your specific problems but gives you an alternatives